# Setting custom top / bottom boundaries

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have boundaries set to the top and bottom edges of the screen, but I wanted to know how I would set top / bottom boundaries within two rectangles on the same screen?

```
   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.view!.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:     UIImage(imageLiteral: "bgImage"))


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    blueBall = SKSpriteNode( imageNamed: "ball1111.png")
    blueBall.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    blueBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: blueBall.size.width / 3.50)

    blueBall.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    blueBall.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
   self.addChild(blueBall)
    blueBall.zPosition = 2

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    let push = CGVectorMake(10, 10)
    blueBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(push)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to change the self.frame in:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

to your custom settings.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how I would do that? Something like this? self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:CGRect(x: <>, y: <>, width: <>, height: <>))

Comment: Thank you for your help!